# Problem with SMS scheduling(Android)

Tags: java, android, sms

I have designed for schedule SMS in android.i set timer for SMS to send by using `CountDownTimer` Constructor class. values for timer assigned,but i cannot start the countdown time even i have passed the timer value and interval values. If i start the constructor manually by using object, the sms is sent immediately(not waiting for the time set). I need to send the sms when the time set to send is reached .Here goes my code. Any Help is Appreciated.

```
new Mycounter(dif, 1000);


// My  Counter timer code goes here

 public class Mycounter extends CountDownTimer
    {

        String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString(); 

        public Mycounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
        {

            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
      @Override
        public void onFinish() {
          sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling start()?
*new Mycounter(dif, 1000).start()*

Otherwise your timer code looks good.
Add few logs.